# string - jquery matching from src inside hidden iframe

Tags: jquery, string, iframe, match, src

The document I am working on has a list of names on a table, each row has a respective unique ID corresponding with the name. What I am trying to do with this is have jquery search for the names in a hidden iframe sourced from another site:

```
<iframe style="display: none" ID="websrc" src="https://sites.google.com/site/andsamyong/"></iframe>

<div id="names">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Name</td></tr>
<tr id="sam"><td>Sam</td></tr>
<tr id="james"><td>James</td></tr>
```

And add the `style="display: none"` attribute to it. Due to Same Origin Policy it may make this unable to be done by simplistic method that I hope to be using as I am not very proficient in Javascript, let alone using Jquery.

Thankyou. - Sam.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible due to the Same Origin Policy unless you have special access from the cross-origin site you are requesting data from. (and since it's google, i'm pretty sure you don't have that access.)

Comment: @user1970542 That's still going to get caught up in the Same Origin Policy. Make the request using your server rather than the client, your server doesn't have a Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Alright, thank-you for the feedback. Just a pity that it can't be done.